# Android : Crash when adding ImageView programmatically?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, onclicklistener

When i am adding `ImageView` programmatically for first time show me `ImageView` but for second time get me crash :

```
    imgtest = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.someID);
            imgtest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Medtconversation = edtconversation.getText().toString();
                    edtconversation.setText("");
                    if(Medtconversation.length() > 0)
                    {
                    if (flagTyp == true) {

I add Image View Here------->imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.chat_logo);
                    --->imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    --->        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    --->        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    --->rilative.addView(imageView);<---- Line 286

                        txtviewUser = new TextView(ConversationPage.this);
                        txtviewUser.setText(Medtconversation);
                        txtviewUser.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                        txtviewUser.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        txtviewUser.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,25);
                        txtviewUser.setPadding(20, 5, 20, 10);

                        rilative.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.conversation_shap);
                        rilative.addView(txtviewUser);

                        MyTaskParams params = new MyTaskParams(Integer
                                .parseInt(UserID), 0, Integer.parseInt(IDEtegh),
                                Integer.parseInt(IDSharee), UserNAME, NSharee,
                                NEtegh, Medtconversation, URL);
                        MySendMessage sendmsg = new MySendMessage();
                        try {
                            String Rest = sendmsg.execute(params).get();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        flagTyp = false;
                    }
                    }
```

And my `Layout Xml` is :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/brown"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lineartwo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:weightSum="1.5" 
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_conversation">

           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/isTyping"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Chat" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtInpuConversation"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:hint="@string/edt_Conversation" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/someID"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/social_send_now" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Error :

```
by Log tag : AndroidRuntime
by Log Message : at com.test.onlinechattwo.ConversationPage$3.onClick(ConversationPage.java:286)
```

Comment: please post your log output

Comment: do you have a imageview in the layout posted? You only have ImageButton

Comment: please post full code of your activity

Comment: what is on line 286 indicate the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your code by carefully, I hope that your chat app is:

[image]

If such is, you should add `ImageView` just one time so edit your code :

```
boolean flgaimage = false; (In you activity)
```

And edit your `ClickListener` :

```
       .........
        if (flagTyp == true) {

            if(flgaimage == false)
            {
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                rilative.addView(imageView);
                flgaimage = true;
            }
        .............
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to add the same instance of imageView every time the onClick is called. The solution is that you have to add the following line before `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.chat_logo)`

```
imageView = new ImageView(Context)
```

I hope that it helps